# How to invert boolean array?

Tags: c#, arrays, boolean

Is there a cleaner way to invert boolean array?

```
var myBoolArray=new bool[]{true, true, true, true, true};
bool[] revertedArray=new bool[5];
for(int i=0;i<myBoolArray.Length;i++)
{
    revertedArray[i]=!myBoolArray[i];
}
```

Atm I'm doing this, but it looks really ugly.

Comment: `new bool[5]`, How do you know it's length 5? And why is it not based on the `myBoolArray.Lenght`?

Comment: Honestly, a `bool[]` is the worst possible way to store bit data (at least without getting silly); in this case, an `int` (or even a `byte`) would be vastly preferable, but for unknown-possibly-large lengths (rather than "at most 32", "at most 64", etc) there's `BitArray`, which also has a `Not()` method; guess what `Not()` does!

Comment: Eh... this was just an simple example compared to the real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a neater way using LINQ, though that's about the only benefit:

```
bool[] invertedArray = myBoolArray.Select(b => !b).ToArray();
```

Comment: @SomeBody It seems that OP _wants_ a new array.

Comment: But that allocates new array in memory to do something that can be done in place.

Comment: @LukaszNowakowski But did OP want to do it in place? It's not going to always be the case that you want to mutate the input. In OP's question they had two arrays at the end. I sense people are getting here from another question that was clear about not wanting a new array.

Comment: I noticed that right after I sent my reply. But also take into account that bit from his comment "Eh... this was just an simple example compared to the real code". But you're right I stand corrected. Although I wasn't redirected from question you mentioned :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.convertall?view=net-7.0) which is more performant than LINQ here.

```cs
var myBoolArray = new bool[] { true, true, true, true, true };
bool[] invertedArray = Array.ConvertAll(myBoolArray, b => !b);
```

Comment: It is not more performant than LINQ. ProgrammingLlama's answer is equally performant. Since `myBoolArray` is an array then LINQ's `Select` operator returns an `IIListProvider<bool>` which will preallocate an array on `ToArray()`.

Comment: Please just take a look at this [benchmark](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7rGy0h). Linq is indeed slightly slower. Or what am I missing here?

Comment: That's not a very good benchmark. Here's a better one. It's far more stable. https://dotnetfiddle.net/RnNaac

Comment: It does show that `ConvertAll` is faster.

Comment: Try this variation on your benchmark to see why yours was particularly bad. https://dotnetfiddle.net/fSOUbM

Comment: Whoops, there was a bug in my benchmark. Here's an update: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JMEJVt